# php validation through use own function not working

Tags: php, function

i want to use self define function in my script but i don't know how to use self define function.i tried a little but it doesn't work please help out.if you have idea please share it.

```
 $fname=$_GET['fname'];
    $lname=$_GET['lname'];
    $submit=$_GET['submit'];
    $error=array();

        function validation($fname,$lname,$submit){
            if(isset($submit))
            {
                if(empty($fname)){
                    return "first name field is empty";
                }

                if(!empty($fname)){
                    if(!is_string($fname))
                    {
                        return "please type alphabet in firstname field";
                    }    
                }

                if(empty($lname)){
                    return "last name field is empty";
                }

                if(!empty($lname)){
                    if(!is_string($lname)){
                        return "please type alphabet in lastname field";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        validation();
```

if you have any link regarding use of self define functions please share it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just call `validation()` without any parameters, when you ask for them with the line `($fname,$lname,$submit)`.  Call it like `validation($_GET['fname'], $_GET['lname'], $_GET['submit']);`.

EDIT: Looking at the updated code, you've got a scoping issue essentially.  Don't declare the `$fname`, `$lname`, etc vars outside of the function.  Just pass them in.

Also, you're checking `if (!empty($lname))`, but that check is pointless.  If it was empty, your function would have returned.  You can be 100% sure that it is not empty at that point, so there is no point in checking.

A link for further reading on functions in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: :-what i have to change...1)function validation($fname,$lname,$submit) or function validation();

Comment: @user1817669 I don't understand your question.  You should keep your function definition as is, but change your function call, i.e. where you do `validation()`.

Comment: can i parameter to function validation($fname,$lname,$submit){ .....//// } or function validation($_GET['fname'], $_GET['lname'], $_GET['submit']){ .....//// }

Comment: @mesh:-i'm getting a blank page.i want validate my html form with the help of self defining function.if you know please help me out how i implement function in my script.thank for your valuable support